# How to make a directory name with quotes in it, such as "What's for dinner?"

Tags: command-line

I'm having a hard time making this directory in the terminal. I tried

```
mkdir '"What's for dinner?"'
```

but I think that doesn't work because of the apostrophe in `What's`. So I tried escaping that apostrophe:

```
mkdir '"What\'s for dinner?"'
```

but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

edit: I want to keep the double quotes in the directory name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to create folder with quotes you should escape it using double quotes `"` and `\`:

```
mkdir "\"\""
```

Will create folder `""`

```
mkdir "\"\"'"
```

Will create folder `""'`

```
mkdir "'"
```

Will create folder `'`

```
mkdir "\"What's for dinner?\""
```

Will create what you want

Answer (score 4):

Inside single quotes, all the characters are taken literally.  However, that also means that you cannot put a single-quote inside single-quotes.  The solution is to have to single-quoted strings with an escaped single-quote between them:

```
mkdir '"What'\''s for dinner?"'
```

In the above `'"What'` is a single-quoted string. It is followed by `\'` which is an escaped single-quote.  And, that is followed by the single-quoted string `'s for dinner?"'`.

The above works well because the rules are simple.

Another approach is the `$'...'` construct.  Using that:

```
mkdir $'"What\'s for dinner?"'
```

The `$'...'` form does support many escaped characters including `\'` for single-quote.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes from your code like this,

```
mkdir "What's for dinner?"
```

This will create a  directory named `What's for dinner?`

**Update:**

```
mkdir "'What's for dinner?'"
```

This will create a  directory named `'What's for dinner?'`

**Update 1:**

```
mkdir "\"What's for dinner?"\"
```

This will create a  directory named `"What's for dinner?"`

Comment: But I want the quotes to be kept in the directory name.

Comment: You want both single and double quotes?

Comment: Just the double quotes. If I type `ls . -d`, I want to see `"What's for dinner?"`

Comment: Now try my update1.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to name your directory

```
"\?$*’KwaMe’*$?\"
```

you have to type

```
mkdir \"\\\?\$\*\’\K\w\a\M\e\’\*\$\?\\\"\
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape each symbol character with `\` like so :

```
$ mkdir What\'s\ for\ dinner\?
```